# Fetching all images src from specific div

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument, domparser

Suppose, I have HTML structure like:

```
 <div>
      <div class="content">
           <p>This is dummy text</p>
           <p><img src="a.jpg"></p>
           <p>This is dummy text</p>
           <p><img src="b.jpg"></p>
      </div>
 </div>
```

I want to fetch all image src from `.content` div. I tried :

```
 <?php
 // a new dom object
 $dom = new domDocument; 

 // load the html into the object
 $dom->loadHTML("example.com/article/2345"); 

 // discard white space
 $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
 //get element by class
 $finder = new DomXPath($dom);
 $classname = 'content';
 $content = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
 foreach($content as $item){
    echo $item->nodevalue;
 }
```

But, I cannot get anything when I loop through `$content`. PLease Help.

Comment: Post your loop code please ?

Comment: yeah. I have posted.

Comment: I can see the dummy text bit in the loop, heres the fiddle - https://3v4l.org/MXSK7 , are you sure the structure of what you get from example.com/article/2345 is same as your sample structure

Comment: Its not in same structure but I want to fetch all image from content class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your XPath query as shown below:

```
// loading html content from remote url
$html = file_get_contents("http://nepalpati.com/entertainment/22577/");
@$dom->loadHTML($html);  
...
$classname = 'content';
$img_sources = [];

// getting all images within div with class "content"
$content = $finder->query("//div[@class='$classname']/p/img");
foreach ($content as $img) {
    $img_sources[] = $img->getAttribute('src');
}
...
var_dump($img_sources);
// the output:

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(68) "http://nepalpati.com/mediastorage/images/2072/Falgun/khole-selfi.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(72) "http://nepalpati.com/mediastorage/images/2072/Falgun/khole-hot-selfi.jpg"
}
```

Comment: I got an empty array.

Comment: @user254153, oh, yes. Just a little fix. Check this out. It should work

Comment: `$dom->loadHTML("example.com/article/2345"); ` is not loading any html for me. Is there any problem.

Comment: did you see my output above? It works. How do you get that html, local address or remote ?

Comment: I get html from remote. But its not exactly the same. `http://nepalpati.com/entertainment/22577/` Can you please try for this link and help to see if it successfully works.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the way you should load that html content. Enjoy

Comment: Thank you.. It worked. But I changed `$img_sources = array();`