# Get src attribute of specific image with DOM PHP

Tags: php, dom, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to do the same that this jQuery function in PHP (FB Open Graph doesn't execute JS Code, so it has to be executed server side) :

```
    <script>captureurl=jQuery('.blog-content').find('img').attr('src');
jQuery('head').append("<meta property='og:image' content="+captureurl+"/></meta>");</script>
```

I've seen I could get an image attribute like that :

```
<?php doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$imgs = $xpath->query("//img");
for ($i=0; $i < $imgs->length; $i++) {
    $img = $imgs->item($i);
    $src = $img->getAttribute("src");
    // do something with $src
} ?>
```

But how can I target the first image src in the div with .blog-content class?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching all images src from specific div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646107/fetching-all-images-src-from-specific-div)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$xpath->query("//img")` with following:

```
$imgs = $xpath->query('//img[contains(attribute::class, "blog-content")]'); //here we are querying domdocument to find img which has class .blog-content
```

Comment: You should add an explanation as well. Then it's easier for the OP (and other future readers) to use it and change it to fit their needs in other situations.